# how to using the erlang re module to replace string using backward reference

Tags: reference, erlang, expression

I am trying to use a [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) re module to finish the replacement like:

```
re:replace("+462223334", "^+46(.*)$","sip:46\1@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone",[{return,list}]).
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  re:replace/4
    called as re:replace("+462223334","^+46(.*)$",
                         [115,105,112,58,52,54,1,64,112,98,120,55,56,53,
                         46,116,99,101,120,112,111,46,105,99,115,46|...],
                         [{return,list}])
```

But it failed. Except I write like this:

```
re:replace("+462223334", "^\\\\+46(.*)$","sip:46 \\\1@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone",[{return,list}]).
"sip:462223334@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone"
```

Is there a better way to do such replacement? Like using some options in re module.

or fix the arguments before replace, like add two slash before `+`, and add one more slash before `\1`. Even these fixing is not convenient using [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) lib.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way around that since both regex and Erlang use `\` for escaping, so to send `\\+` to `re`, you have to write `\\\\+` and to send `\1`, you have to write `\\\1`, but in this particular case you can also use pattern matching:

```
1> case "+462223334" of
1>   "+46" ++ Rest -> "sip:46" ++ Rest ++ "@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone";
1>   Otherwise -> Otherwise
1> end.
"sip:462223334@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone"
```

This will work identical to your `re:replace`, and will most likely be more efficient.

---

If you know the string will always start with `+46`, you can even do this:

```
1> "+46" ++ Rest = "+462223334".
"+462223334"
2> "sip:46" ++ Rest ++ "@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone".
"sip:462223334@pbx785.tcexpo.ics.se;user=phone"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! but we shall use back reference. like in this case, "\1" stands for the first matched part:  +462223334 match with ^+46(.*)$, the \1 equals to "2223334". and it can be any regular expression and many back references, like \2 , \3 and so on. So we cannot assume the input format.

Comment: Ah. In that case you'll have to escape the characters like you already figured out. When you type `"\\1"`, what Erlang sees after the tokenizing/lexing stage is just a string containing a slash followed by `1`.